# What is parser use Stax to DOM?

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have  a XML file whit 25 000 record. What parser is best for this XML, Stax or DOM?

```
    SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="https://webapi.allegro.pl/service.php">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:doGetCatsDataResponse>
         <ns1:catsList>
            <ns1:item>
               <ns1:catId>26013</ns1:catId>
               <ns1:catName>Antyki i Sztuka</ns1:catName>
               <ns1:catParent>0</ns1:catParent>
               <ns1:catPosition>0</ns1:catPosition>
               <ns1:catIsProductCatalogueEnabled>0</ns1:catIsProductCatalogueEnabled>
            </ns1:item>
            <ns1:item>
               <ns1:catId>98553</ns1:catId>
               <ns1:catName>Bilety</ns1:catName>
               <ns1:catParent>0</ns1:catParent>
               <ns1:catPosition>1</ns1:catPosition>
               <ns1:catIsProductCatalogueEnabled>0</ns1:catIsProductCatalogueEnabled>
            </ns1:item>
            <ns1:item> 
      .......
```

Answer (score 1):

With regards to memory and speed, when you have a huge XML in hand, its better to go with SAX/StAX instead of a DOM parser. Thats because a DOM parser will load the complete XML into memory and construct a tree which would take up even more memory. SAX/StAX on the other hand does not load the file and only scans the XML one element at a time.

Comment: @Monaco.. let me know if you need additional information. Cos I am currently working on similar kind of stuff